# Transparency lost when converting PDF to PDF/X1a with Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript, pdftk

We need to convert PDFs created with ApacheFOP and merged with `pdftk` to PDF/X-1a. I already created a `PDFX_def.ps` with the following content:

```
%!
% This is a sample prefix file for creating a PDF/X-3 document.
% Feel free to modify entries marked with "Customize".
% This assumes an ICC profile to reside in the file (ISO Coated sb.icc),
% unless the user modifies the corresponding line below.
systemdict /ProcessColorModel known {
systemdict /ProcessColorModel get dup /DeviceGray ne exch /DeviceCMYK ne and
} {
true
} ifelse
{ (ERROR: ProcessColorModel must be /DeviceGray or DeviceCMYK.)=
/ProcessColorModel cvx /rangecheck signalerror
} if
% Define entries to the document Info dictionary :
[ /GTS_PDFXVersion (PDF/X-1:2001) % Must be so (the standard requires).
/GTS_PDFXConformance (PDF/X-1a:2001)
/Title (Title) % Customize.
/Trapped /False % Must be so (Ghostscript doesn't provide other).
/DOCINFO pdfmark
% Define an ICC profile :
/ICCProfile (/var/www/share/data/files/sRGB_IEC61966-2-1_black_scaled.icc) def % Customize or remove.
currentdict /ICCProfile known {
[/_objdef {icc_PDFX} /type /stream /OBJ pdfmark
[{icc_PDFX} <</N>> /PUT pdfmark
[{icc_PDFX} ICCProfile (r) file /PUT pdfmark} if
%Define the output intent dictionary :
[/_objdef {OutputIntent_PDFX} /type /dict /OBJ pdfmark
[{OutputIntent_PDFX} <<
/Type /OutputIntent % Must be so (the standard requires).
/S /GTS_PDFX % Must be so (the standard requires).
/OutputCondition (Commercial and specialty printing) % Customize
/Info (none) % Customize
/OutputConditionIdentifier (CGATS TR001) % Customize
/RegistryName (http://www.color.org) % Must be so (the standard requires).
currentdict /ICCProfile known {
/DestOutputProfile {icc_PDFX} % Must be so (see above).
} if
>> /PUT pdfmark
[{Catalog} <</OutputIntents [ {OutputIntent_PDFX} ]>> /PUT pdfmark
```

Then I use this file in the following command:

```
gs -dPDFX -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOOUTERSAVE -dUseCIEColor \
   -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -sOutputFile=output-x1a.pdf PDFX_def.ps output.pdf
```

I'm using Ghostscript 9.05 and here are links to the original and the resulting PDF:

- http://content.kartenmacherei.de/original.pdf
- http://content.kartenmacherei.de/pdfx1a_example.pdf

**As you can see on the PDF files the transparency around the image is lost. Do you know how to fix it? Or a better way to create a PDF/X1a file out of the original file with Debian?**

Comment: A better question title for this would be "transparency in image lost when converting..."

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use Ghostscript to reliably create a PDF/X1-a PDF file. The PDF/X-1a format limits colour spaces in a way which older versions of the `pdfwrite` devices cannot, and newer versions do not, support.

PDF/X1-a doesn't support transparency, so you can't produce a PDF/X-1a file with transparency anyway, if you try this with Ghostscript it will simply create a PDF file which contains a large bitmap image.

You should also use a more recent version of Ghostscript, though this won't permit you to create a PDF/X1-a file anyway. I can't see anything except the 'original' in the URL quoted above, so I can't say if there's some problem with the output file.

NB as I keep on telling people, when you use pdfwrite you are not 'converting' an input PDF file, you are creating a brand new PDF file based on the marking operators present in the original PDF file. However the actual new page description does not necessarily bear any relation to the original one.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Do you know any other way cli based? 2) How can I convert to PDF/X3 (which should be possible with gs)? Therefore I need a def.ps file..

Comment: The pdfx_def.ps file will produce a valid PDF/X3 file (I just checked with the Acrobat preflight). However, there is something odd about the colour of the first page (the transparency is correct with current code though). The only other tool I know of which will create a PDF/X file from a generic PDF file is Acrobat. Note that, since PDF/X3 doesn't support transparency either, you are still going to end up with page 1 being a big bitmap image.

Comment: So far the bitmap is fine from our point of view. But what happens if I have two vectors overlapping eachother (especially with a font on top of them)? Are the rasterized?

Comment: Any page with transparency is rendered to an image.